# Is it possible to publish a service contract for dotnetcore WebApi services?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm looking into picking up WebApi on dotnetcore after previously working with WCF/SOAP and ServiceStack/REST services.

Under both of these other service hosting models I was able to publish the service contracts as a standalone NuGet package for others to consume.

Is it possible to do the same with dotnetcore? I would like to publish a NuGet package that contains a C# representation (as a DTO) of the resources the service accepts and some metadata on the routes for each resource.

Edit: I would preferably like to do this without having to pull in another framework.

Comment: Note ServiceStack also supports and lets you do this with .NET Core http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore - If you’re only looking for how to do this with WebApi you should specify so in your question.

Comment: @mythz good point!

Comment: I mean make it clear in your question title, since it sounds like you only want to do this using only WebApi, i.e. not just .NET Core.

Comment: Well, on a very basic level, you can simply move your DTOs into a class library and then set that project up to produce a NuGet package on build.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Is it possible to use dtos when configuring endpoints for WebApi?

Comment: What do you mean? It's a "rose by any other name" situation. A DTO is just a class. Yes, you can have your actions accept classes and return classes, so yes you can use DTOs.

Comment: @ChrisPratt ideally I would like to expose more than just the DTOs, be it the routing information or some sort of thin proxy that accepts an http client of the consumer's choice. Is it possible to extract/attach the routing information to the DTO?

Comment: Well, you're dealing with a REST-based API now, so it's not quite the same. However, you can use libraries like Swashbuckle or NSwag to generate automatic API documentation and libraries like AutoRest to automatically generate clients from said documentation. I believe NSwag also does client generation too.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks, I will take a look at those